# Lightbox plugin for large captions

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am builing a jQuery based website with an integrated CMS (CouchCMS). The website basically consists of pictures with lenthy description. Both, the picture and the description should be seen at the same time.

I am in need of a lightbox plugin (preferably compatible with jQuery) that can display an image with a lot of text in the caption. I have tried the "Magnific Lightbox" but a caption with a lot of text overlaps the picture. I am looking for a lightbox plugin that would ideally have a scrollable caption.

Does any one know of a CMS-friendly lightbox plugin that serves my needs? Or is there a different implementation method that would allow for a clear layout?

Cheers!

I have tried Simple Lightbox and Magnific Lightbox

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try fancybox (https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/). It has scrollable caption by default, but you can easily change layout using CSS so it would suit better for lengthy captions. Examples - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/vQGGYE https://codepen.io/fancyapps/full/pxovaa

```
.fancybox-caption {
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: 44px;
    top: 0;
    width: 256px;
}

/* etc... */
```